# How can I run Sesame (Lastpass) program on a USB on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, 16.04

I sent LastPass support the following message: "I downloaded Sesame for Ubuntu/Debian to a USB flash drive to use on Ubuntu. As instructed by LastPass, I ran `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates libssl0.9.8` and got the following response:

```
Package libssl0.9.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.

E: Package 'libssl0.9.8' has no installation candidate.
```

Can you help?"

I got the following reply from LastPass support:

```
For now, LastPass will not work without libssl 0.9.8 installed.
```

If you need to use the program, you will need to pull the package itself, since it is part of the sources:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727433/how-to-completly-remove-openssl-installed-via-sources-in-ubuntu.

Then you will need to install the older version of libssl http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl0.9.8."

Since I am a Ubuntu/Linux newbie, I do not understand their reply. Can anyone here help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem after doing a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Here's what I did to resolve the problem:

1. Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libssl0.9.8/download and download the appropriate file for your machine.  Since I have a 32-bit machine I downloaded the i386 version of the libssl0.9.8 file (libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_i386.deb).
2. Go to Ubuntu Software and download GDebi Package Installer.  You'll use this software app to install the *.deb file downloaded in Step 1 above.
3. Open GDebi and click on File|Open and browse to the folder where you downloaded the libssl0.9.8 file (usually this will be the Downloads folder).

I already had sesame saved to a USB drive so once I installed libssl0.9.8 file, I opened up Terminal from the Launcher and changed the directory to the USB drive where I had sesame saved.  For example,

```
$ cd /media/<user name>/<usb drive name>/
$ sudo ./sesame
```

Replace  with your user name and  with your drive name.